# handlebars and countdown inside template

Tags: jquery, plugins, handlebars.js, countdown

Using [Final Countdown Plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) and [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Both plugins works great, separately. The following `<div>` will give me a countdown (here countdown to 2017/01/01):

```
         <div id="getting-started"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#getting-started").countdown("2017/01/01", function(event) {
               $(this).text(
                  event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
               );
            });
         </script>
```

I have a simple handlebars example here:

```
        <script type ="mustache/x.tmpl" id="helloTmpl">
           {{#each this}}
              {{endTime}}
           {{/each}}
        </script>
```

Where `{{endTime}}` is the end time I would like a countdown to (instead of 2017/01/01). It is inside the `{{#each}}` loop and there will run many `{{endTime}}`.

Anyone know an idea to make this possible? And get a countdown for every `{{endTime}}`? I tried to put the above countdown plugin into a helper but with no success and it became a bit messy. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Result**

Thanks @76484. By puzzling with your example I now got it to work with my setup, great! I run `function populate()` every 3-5 sec to refresh my template with new data. This now means I also have to run the countdown function each 3-5 sec, even though the `endTime` data doesn't change. I do like this:

```
            function populate()
            {

                var url = apiurl + 'api/myGreatData';
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false, 
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) 
                    {
                        var source = document.getElementById("helloTmpl").innerHTML;

                        var tmpl= Handlebars.compile(source);

                        var html = tmpl(response);

                        var box = document.getElementById("box");

                        box.innerHTML = html;

                        // Countdown Timer
                        $('[data-countdown]').each(function (index, el) {
                            var $el = $(el);
                            var finalDate = $el.attr('data-countdown');

                            $el.countdown(finalDate, function (event) {
                                $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
                            });
                        }); 

                    }
                })
            }
```

For some reason I feel it would be even greater if the countdown timer could be outside this `function populate()` with ajax, but then it wont work due to your DOM explanation. Perhaps the extra burden by calling countdown is too insignificant as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing difficult about what you are trying to do. The only rule is that you must make sure your `endTime` elements are added to the DOM *before* you invoke the plugin.

You need to add an HTML element into your template that the plugin will be bound to. Also, I don't know what `endTime` is since you did not include your data structure. I will assume a simpler data structure - an array of end time strings:

```
var endTimes = [
    '2017/01/01',
    '2018/02/02',
    '2019/03/03'
];
```

We will need a way to obtain each countdown element's final date for when we invoke the plugin. I will make this possible by adding a data-attribute, `data-countdown`, to the element in the template:

```
<script type="mustache/x.tmpl" id="helloTmpl">
    {{#each this}}
        <div data-countdown="{{.}}"></div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Once we have added all of our countdown elements to the DOM, we are ready to invoke the plugin. We will loop over each element with a `data-countdown` attribute, get the `finalDate` value from this attribute, and then invoke the plugin for that element:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#helloTmpl').html());
$('#Container').html(template(endTimes));

$('[data-countdown]').each(function (index, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var finalDate = $el.attr('data-countdown');

    $el.countdown(finalDate, function (event) {
        $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
});
```

Here is an [example in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/9836rpbx/).

Comment: What data are you fetching every 3 - 5 seconds?

Comment: I am just echoing encoded json.. E.g. I have `{{enrolledParticipants}}` that can increase if some user enroll a "tour".. Every user need to see this change dynamically (or in every 3-5sek). Each tour has the `{{endTime}}`  as you know, and this is a constant for each tour. There can be added more tours over time, but the template loop `{{each this}}` handles this. In future I will however make the ajax run if change happens on server instead of 3-5 sec refreshes, but the point is still the same with the countdown clock inside Ajax...

Comment: Your code could be refactored to achieve some efficiencies. For example, there is no need to compile the template _every_ time you get a successful AJAX response.

Comment: but will that not hurt the `{{enrolledParticipants}}` if this one increase? I am not sure how you would do that, or it is at least currently out of my scope of knowledge